# Get list of students with max number in each class

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the list of students from db, who have get maximum number in each class with student name. Using MySQL DB.

I have the following tables like Student, classes, result (with different years results)

Tables structure student(student_id,student_name,class_id,address), class(class_id,class_name), results(result_id,student_id,year,marks)

and I need list like

```
Student Name   class   Marks
Jon            A-1      800
Steve          B-1      789
```

Comment: I guess you missed to include the complete table structure.

Comment: how about including some more information like: database, version, columns, data, expected result, what you already tried

Comment: I am using MySQL db. for further detail have update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** corrected code, comment was correct

Try the code on this [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6102d/1)

Comment: Now your student name is random.  Best for class B-1 should be Ana not Steve.  Thanks for linking the SQL Fiddle, I reused it!

Comment: Corrected, just needed to change the [GROUP BY] clause by class name to get the max results by class

Comment: Yes, you where right @Andomar, students names where selected randomly. Needed a subquery to get the correct on, similar to your solution indeed but using `MAX`instead `LIMIT`. Corrected and tested

Answer (score 3):

You could use a subquery to filter the students with the highest mark per class:

```
select  s.student_name
,       c.class_name
,       r.marks
from    results r
join    student s
on      r.student_id = s.student_id
join    class c
on      c.class_id = s.class_id
where   r.result_id =
        (
        select  r2.result_id
        from    student s2
        join    results r2
        on      s2.student_id = r2.student_id
        where   c.class_id = s2.class_id
        order by
                r2.marks desc
        limit   1
        )
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/731a9/2/0)

Comment: That's another option, but using `GROUP BY` and `MAX` is clearer, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

```
select s1.student_name, c1.class_name, r1.marks 
from student s1, class c1, results r1,
  (select s2.class_id, max(r2.marks) marks 
   from results r2, student s2
   where r2.student_id = s2.student_id 
   group by s2.class_id) agg
where r1.marks      = agg.marks 
  and r1.student_id = s1.student_id
  and s1.class_id   = c1.class_id
  and s1.class_id   = agg.class_id
```